# VS Code karate config js error while running scenario with java 1.8 and karate version 1.2.0.RC5

Tags: visual-studio-code, karate

I am getting following error while running a scenario file from VS Code with Java 1.8 and karate version 1.2.0.RC5:

```
  ERROR com.intuit.karate - src/test/java/feature/FOC.feature:5
  * url baseUrl
  js failed:

 01: baseUrl

   org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "baseUrl" is not defined
   - <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
```

karate-config.js file:

```
   function fn() {
       var env = karate.env; // get system property 'karate.env'
     karate.log('karate.env system property was:', env);
     if (!env) {
        env = 'qa';
    }
    var config = {
        secretKey: 'ssshhhhhhhhhhh!!!!',
        // myVarName: 'someValue'
    }
    if (env == 'dev') {
        config.baseUrl = 'https://services-dev.com/'
 
    } else if (env == 'qa') {
        config.baseUrl = 'https://services-qa.com/'
 
    }
    var result = karate.callSingle('classpath:tlrservice/feature/tripIdGenaration.feature');
    config.tripIdGenaration = result;
    return config;
  }
```

feature file:

```
Feature: Test

  Background:
    * url baseUrl
```

Comment: clearly `config.baseUrl` is not set. please start with the ZIP release if you are new to this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/ZIP-Release - or ask questions on the karate-runner project: https://github.com/kirksl/karate-runner/issues

Comment: I tried 1.2.0 RC1 zip release but getting same error

Comment: I have nothing more to add here

Comment: Thank you I have created issue in github as suggested.